# Not possible to bypass proxy on UWP mobile device?

Tags: c#, mobile, proxy, win-universal-app

I am fairly new to UWP apps development and I created simple UWP app (mainly targeting phones) for purpose of testing and demonstrating behavior of Http libraries on UWP (like System.Net.Http).
One of the scenarios should demonstrate bypassing proxy

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.UseProxy = false;
httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

but the request send using this setting still goes through proxy (proxy is set in Internet APN settings on the phone).
So I am a bit confused here and feel like I am missing something, and I hope someone will be kind enough to answer me a few questions to help me get the right picture :).

1.) I read documentation and some articles on the topic and there is often mentioned System or Default proxy (usualy it says about IE settings). So what does it mean in context of Windows 10? Is it the proxy set in Settings/Network&Internet/Proxy?

1.1) Is there an equivalent on W10 phone?

2.) Is there some other way how to bypass the Internet APN proxy on mobile device, or it is simply not possible and the UseProxy property is just useless in UWP phone apps?

Thanks in advance for your answers :).

[Link to original question on msdn boards](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3552ece9-6d2b-4d09-bb56-27a461a882ac/not-possible-to-bypass-proxy-on-mobile-device?forum=wpdevelop)

What I read behore asking here:
MSDN documentation on related classes and
[Article by program manager on the Windows Networking API](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/)

Answer (score 0):

The preferred HTTP API in UWP apps is `Windows.Web.Http`, you can try:

```
var handler = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter():
habdler.UseProxy = false;
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :) I tried that also, but result is the same as with System.Net.Http library, it still goes through the APN profile proxy.